# Python DiffLib: get_close_matches does not find a value with ratio above cutoff

Tags: python, difflib

I'm experiencing an incoherent result using difflib.get_close_matches.

I'm trying to find best matches of a string ('Adeline,L. Marie') in a list (['L. Marie,Adeline','Allain,Martine', 'Ndiaye,Marie', 'AdelaiDe Mori,Maria'])

```
import difflib    
string = 'Adeline,L. Marie'
list = ['L. Marie,Adeline','Allain,Martine', 'Ndiaye,Marie', 'AdelaiDe Mori,Maria']
matches = difflib.get_close_matches(string, list,3, cutoff=0.4)
print ('Matches found: ' + ";".join(matches))
for element in list:
    print (element + ': ' + str(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'Adeline,L. Marie', element).ratio()))
```

Applying difflib:

```
difflib.get_close_matches(string, list,3, cutoff=0.4)
```

I'm getting three results that according to the available [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) should be "sorted by similarity score, most similar first".

But when I check the similarity score between string and each element of list:

```
for element in list:
    print (element + ': ' + str(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'Adeline,L. Marie', element).ratio()))
```

I don't understand why I'm getting:

```
Matches found: Allain,Martine;Ndiaye,Marie;AdelaiDe Mori,Maria
```

When the first element in the list ('L. Marie,Adeline') has a better score than 'Allain,Martine'.

```
L. Marie,Adeline: 0.5
Allain,Martine: 0.3333333333333333
Ndiaye,Marie: 0.6428571428571429
AdelaiDe Mori,Maria: 0.6285714285714286
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're looping through `list` not through `matches`. Also you should rename `list` as you're clashing with the name of the built-in `list`

Comment: Yes, I'm looping through `list` in order to retrieve the similarity score for all the elements of the list and compare it with the results of the `get_close_matches` function. What I do not understand is why 'L. Marie,Adeline' (score 0.5) is not in the `get_close_matches` results, while 'Allain,Martine' (score 0.33) is.
And yes you're right, I should avoid reserved words but renaming `list` has no effect.